# How to reduce an image resulting from an expression?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, reducers, geemap

In the code below I use the `ee.Image.expression` method to combine two images into one. I am then able to display the resulting image using `geemap`, and the image looks as expected. However when using the `reduceRegion` method on my new image, the value I obtain is 0 regardless of the reducer / geometry / resolution used. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import ee
import geemap
ee.Initialize()

im1 = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8")
im2 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")

# expr = "(B2 > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map and reduceRegion value are correct
# expr = "(b(0) > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map and reduceRegion value are correct
expr = "(b(0) > 0) && (B2 > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map is correct but reduceRegion value is 0

im3 = im1.expression(expr, {'B2': im2.select('discrete_classification')})

region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords = [[80,60],[81,60],[81,61],[80,61]])
print(im3.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), region, 100).getInfo()) # returns 0

Map = geemap.Map(center=[60.5, 80.5], zoom=8)
Map.addLayer(im3, {}, 'constant')
Map.addLayer(region, {}, 'region')
Map
```

[image: Code output]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by re-projecting the resulting image into the [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) coordinate system, although I do not fully understand why this step is needed.

```py
import ee
import geemap
ee.Initialize()

im1 = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8")
im2 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")

# expr = "(B2 > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map and reduceRegion value are correct
# expr = "(b(0) > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map and reduceRegion value are correct
expr = "(b(0) > 0) && (B2 > 0) ? 1 : 0" # Map is correct but reduceRegion value is 0

im3 = im1.expression(expr, {'B2': im2.select('discrete_classification')})
im3 = im3.reproject('EPSG:3857', None, 100) # Re-project the map 

region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords = [[80,60],[81,60],[81,61],[80,61]])
print(im3.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), region, 100).getInfo()) # returns 0

Map = geemap.Map(center=[60.5, 80.5], zoom=8)
Map.addLayer(im3, {}, 'constant')
Map.addLayer(region, {}, 'region')
Map
```